# How to count the number of occurrences of the most repeated value along the time axis? - Xarray python

Tags: python, numpy, count, python-xarray

In a xarray dataset, how can someone count the number of repeated values along the time axis? In more details, I would like to identify for every (lat,lon) pair of coordinates, the number of occurrences of the most repeated value along time. I've tried using `xr.count(dim='time')` but it counts all iterations and I do not know how to specify that I'm only interested in the most repeated value.

Small example:

```
array([[[10., 10., 10., 1., 2., 3., 2.]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) int32 2013 2014 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020
  * lat      (lat) float64 -13.64 
  * lon      (lon) float64 -55.11
```

Output expected (Number of occurrences of the most repeated value):

```
Out: 3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a xarray or numpy operator to do this directly.
However you can find each unique value with `values = np.unique(da)`.
Then for each unique value, count its occurrence with something like :

```
possible_values = np.unique(da)
acc = []
for val in possible_values:
  acc.append( { "value": val, "count": (ds.tmax==val).sum() })
index_of_max = np.argmax(list(map(lambda x: x["count"], acc)))
max = acc[index_of_max]
```

But I think it can be a bit resource intensive.

Comment: Hi Abel, thank you for the answer. Indeed, it works but it takes quite a lot of time because of the for loop structure. But then, neither Xarray nor Numpy  have vectorized functions for this then? That is interesting (and sad) to know. What if the dataset is converted to dataframe, would Pandas be able to make this operation faster? Thanks

Comment: Hey @Henrique, I'm not at all a numpy/xarray/pandas expert so I don't really know how it would be optimized. I know you can create your own vectorized function and use it with xarray.apply_ufunc. But first you must find how to vectorize it...